# Trigger stopped firing

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracleforms

I have build a form in Oracle Form Builder 11g, where I implemented a trigger to clear some fields in another block.

I chose the POST-RECORD-TRIGGER, because it should fire whenever the focus moves from one record to another. And it did work fine until recently. I was just adding to the existing code (which worked before), but for some reason the trigger doesn't fire anymore.

I'm still fairly new to oracle forms and I was wondering if anyone could help me understand the form triggers a little better. What could/should I try, to find the reason for the trigger not firing? Where should I start looking?

Comment: Gives us the code you had and what you added, probably there is something wrong there then

Comment: I was just assigning some values to textfields like `:BLOCK.TXT_ITEM1 :='..' ` I only changed what is assigned to the testfields based on a condition. But the problem is that the trigger itself is never fired. (I added a breakpoint to the first line of the code to check)

Comment: First thing I'd try is to do a full recompilation of the form, as well as any libraries it relies on.